# где взять файл mysite.wsgi? (django 1.8+uwsgi+nginx)

Tags: django, django-admin, gunicorn, uwsgi

Я пытаюсь развернуть сайт на django 1.8 сайт. Использую связку uwsgi+nginx+django, также была попытка с gunicorn

Во всех инструкциях говориться сделать так:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

тоже для gunicorn

И возникает одна и таже ошибка:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
ImportError: No module named sitename.wsgi
```

Что это за файл? Где его взять?
у меня есть только wsgi.py
была попытка создать его вручную, по моим соображениям в нем должно быть следующее:

```
import os, sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sitename.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Но он все равно не работает.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Могу предположить что у вас не указан полный путь к файлу . Постарайтесь внимательно прочитать документацию http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi.html

Answer (score 2):

сегодня развернул uwsgi вот такой командой:

```
uwsgi --http :8888 --wsgi-file test2/wsgi.py
```

обратите внимание атрибут **module** не использую, вместо этого **wsgi-file**

файл wsgi.py django генерирует автоматически при создании проекта, если его всё же нет, то для django 1.8 он должен выглядеть так:

```
"""
WSGI config for testproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named   ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

В документации действительно [написано](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi.html#configuring-and-starting-the-uwsgi-server-for-django):

```
module: модуль WSGI – mysite.wsgi, если вы создавали проект командой startproject.
```

однако при создании проекта командой startproject создаётся именно wsgi.py а не mysite.wsgi - загадка. Может артефакт с какой-то старой версии остался. Я припоминаю, что у нас был такой файл на сервере несколько лет назад.

**UPD** да, действительно, способ настройки с mysite.wsgi был актуален до версии Django 1.3, в документации 1.8 до сих пор не исправили, поразительно. Обычно в Django замечательная документация

**UPD2** вырыл в старом проекте файл django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/path/to/project'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

если вдруг по какой-то причине нужно запустить uwsgi именно с атрибутом **module** не вижу причин, чтобы эта конфигурация не сработала. Только внимательно с путями, в этой конфигурации settings находились в корне, теперь - в отдельной папке проекта, т.е. для django 1.8 надо писать: "projectname.settings"